# Connectedness problem: sequences of points with distances at most $\varepsilon$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

Here's problem 6.1.D (a), page $359$ from Engelking's book, stuck with it for a while.

Verify that if a space $X$ with the topology induced by a metric $p$ is connected, then for every pair $x,y$ of points of $X$ and any $\varepsilon >0$ there exists a finite sequence $x_{1},x_{2},..,x_{k}$ of points of $X$ such that $x_{1}=x$, $x_{k}=y$ and $p(x_{i},x_{i+1})<\varepsilon$ for $i=1,2,..,k-1$.

Comment: Needless to say, the converse is false.

Comment: @PseudoNeo: what is a counterexample?

Comment: Try the rationals in [0,1].   This is extremally disconnected but it enjoys this "lilypad property".  Could adding completeness to the hypothesis give a converse?

Comment: @ncmathsadist: compactness is enough (if disconnected, the two pieces must be a positive distance apart), but completeness is not (for example, the union of the x axis and the curve $xy=1$ in the plane).

Comment: See also: [Show that a connected metric space is $\epsilon$-chainable for $\epsilon>0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231699/show-that-a-connected-metric-space-is-epsilon-chainable-for-epsilon0)

Comment: It seems like adding connectedness of balls would be enough to give a converse. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91006/about-a-finite-chain-of-connected-sets and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44850/locally-constant-functions-on-connected-spaces-are-constant/44938#44938

Comment: For reference, this is also an exercise in Joshi's Intro to General Topology p. 148.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Hint.** Fix a point $x\in X$.  Now put
$$Q = \{y\in X| \exists x_1, x_2, \cdots ,x_n\in X \hbox{ with } p(x_k,x_{k+1}) < \epsilon\}.$$
Show that $Q$ is both open  and closed in $X$.  Your result will follow right away.

Comment: that's a nice approach, I will try this,thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical application of the chain lemma from my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44850/locally-constant-functions-on-connected-spaces-are-constant/44938#44938).
Use the open cover by balls of radius $\varepsilon$, and use the centres plus intersection points.