# $\{U_{\alpha} \}$ is a collection of connected sets in a metric space such that no two connected sets in the collection is disjoint ...

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

If $\{U_{\alpha} \}$ is a collection of connected sets in a metric space such that no two connected sets in the collection is disjoint , then is the union of all the sets in the collection  connected ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/521867/family-of-connected-sets-proving-union-is-connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is connected.  Suppose

$$
W\cup V \;\; = \;\; \bigcup_\alpha U_\alpha
$$

Where $W$ and $V$ are disjoint nonempty and open.  Note that $W\cap U_\alpha\neq \emptyset$ for some $\alpha$ hence $U_\alpha \subseteq W$.  But since $U_\beta$ intersects $U_\alpha$ for each $\beta$ we must have $U_\beta \subseteq W$ as well, contradicting the fact that  $V\neq \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

Contradiction is definitely an easy way to complete this proof. Suppose FTSOC that $$\bigcup_{\alpha}U_\alpha = A \cup B$$ where $A,B$ are separated, nonempty sets. It follows that $U_\alpha \subset A\cup B$ for each $\alpha$. Further, since each $U_\alpha$ is a connected subset then either $U_\alpha \subset A$ or $U_\alpha \subset B$, but both cannot be true at the same time. If for all $\alpha$ we had $U_\alpha \subset A$, then $B$ would be empty. We assumed $B$ wasn't empty so there must be at least one $U_{\alpha_{1}} \subset B$. There must also be at least one $U_{\alpha_{2}} \subset A$ by similar reasoning. By separateness of $A$ and $B$ it follows that $U_{\alpha_{1}} \cap U_{\alpha_{2}}=\emptyset$, a contradiction.