# $\{U_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha \in I}$ collection of connected sets , for every $U_{\alpha}$ , $\exists U_{\beta}\ne U_{\alpha}$ not mutually disjoint

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

A probable further strengthening of [$\{U_{\alpha} \}$ is a collection of connected sets in a metric space such that no two connected sets in the collection is disjoint ...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1204419/u-alpha-is-a-collection-of-connected-sets-in-a-metric-space-such-that) If $\{U_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha \in I}$ is a collection of connected sets in a metric space such that for every $U_{\alpha}$ in the collection , there is $U_{\beta}$ in the collection , distinct from $U_{\alpha}$ , such that $U_{\alpha} \cap U_{\beta} \ne \phi$  , then is the union of all the sets in the collection i.e. $\cup_{\alpha \in I}U_{\alpha}$  connected ?

$\Bbb EDIT :$ Does it hold in $\mathbb R^n$ with $n \ge 2$ , with usual Euclidean metric ? Does it hold in real normed linear spaces of dimension more than $1$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take the intervals $U_1 = (0,1)$, $U_2 = (.5,1.5)$, $U_3 = (2,3)$, $U_4 = (2.5,3.5)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology.

Similar examples exist in any metric space (with at least six points), including $\mathbb{R}^n$ for any $n > 0$.

You need a stronger connectivity condition, that there is a chain of connected elements from any $U_\alpha$ to any other $U_\beta$. In other words, if you make a graph whose vertices are $\{ U_\alpha : \alpha \in I\}$, with an edge from $U_\alpha$ to $U_\beta$ whenever $U_\alpha \cap U_\beta \neq \emptyset$, then the connected components of your graph correspond to subsets of the collection whose union is connected.

The connectivity of these unions was addressed in the question [Family of connected sets, proving union is connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/521867/family-of-connected-sets-proving-union-is-connected).

Comment: Thanks , I have added more to the question , please take a look at it

Comment: Could you please state explicitly and give an exposition of the proof of the stronger connectivity condition ; or should I ask it as a new question ?

Comment: @user123733: That was answered in this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/521867/family-of-connected-sets-proving-union-is-connected