# Show that in a topological group $D := \{(p,q) \in G \times G: pq^{-1} \in U\}$ is connected

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups, connectedness, topological-groups

Let $G$ a connected topological group, consider $G \times G$ and denote with $\Delta$ the diagonal of $G \times G$. Fix $U$ a symmetric open neighborhood of $e_G$. Define $$D := \{(p,q) \in G \times G: pq^{-1} \in U\}$$

I want to prove that $D$ is connected. I first noticed that $D \supseteq \Delta $ and that $D$ is open since is the preimage of the map $(p,q) \to pq^{-1}$, hence $D$ is an open neighborhood of the diagonal. Then I rewrote $D$ as $$D = \bigcup\limits_{q \in G}\{q\}\times Uq$$

In this way $D$ can be seen as a union of disjoint connected set intersecting a connected set, i.e $\Delta$, but I'm unable to conclude from here.

Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Every point in $\Delta$ belongs to the connected component of $(e,e)$. You showed that every point in $D$ belongs to the connected component of some point in $\Delta$. All you need now is that this relationship is transitive (in fact it is an equivalence relationship).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/521886/386889

Comment: @freakish In order to clarify and understand,  are you suggesting to prove that $D$ equals the connected component of $(e,e)$ in $D$?

Comment: @jacopoburelli yes, that's right.