# $\partial f = 0 \implies f$ is constant

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $E$ and $F$ be Banach spaces and let $X \subset E$ be a connected open subset. I am trying to show that
if that derivative function $\partial f: X \rightarrow \mathcal{L}(E, F)$ is identically $0$
on $X$ then $f$ must be constant.

Since $X$ is open, for any given $x_0 \in X$, we can find an open ball about $x_0$, $\mathbb{B}_{\epsilon}(x_0)$, 
such that  $\mathbb{B}_{\epsilon}(x_0) \subset X$. Since the open ball is connected, we can apply the
integral mean value theorem to conclude that

$$ \|f(x) - f(x_0) \| = 0 \implies f(x) = f(x_0), \ \forall \; x \in \mathbb{B}_{\epsilon}(x_0) .$$

It follows that $f$ is locally constant. Now, from [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44850/locally-constant-functions-on-connected-spaces-are-constant) 
we know that $f$ is constant on $X$. I am trying to follow an argument however that does not make use of this
result. Let $y_0 = f(x_0)$. Then, since $\partial f$ exists, $f$ is continuous, and from this it follows that the (non-empty)
fiber $f^{-1}(y_0)$ is closed. If we can show that $f^{-1}(y_0)$ is also open we can use the hypothesis that $X$ is
connected to conclude that $f^{-1}(y_0) = X$ and so $f$ must be constant. I'm stuck on this point. Therefore,
my question is:

Within the context of the preceding paragraph, how can we conclude that $f^{-1}(y_0)$ must be open?

Comment: BTW, once you start using the continuity method (open+closed+non-empty = whole space), your proof cannot really be different from the result you linked to, as you can simply rearrange the arguments given in that link into an argument by continuity.

Comment: @Willie The argument I'm following, which purports to be a "proof" does not make use of any of these arguments but flatly concludes, as in "clearly" that $f^{-1}(y_0)$ is open which leads me to believe there is some basic fact that I'm overlooking. I can throw away that argument and simply use the result I linked to but would still like to know why it is "immediate" or "clear" that $f^{-1}(y_0)$ must be open.

Comment: The definition of local constancy immediately implies that $f^{-1}(y_0)$ cannot contain a boundary point. Of course, "clearly" is a weasel word: what is clear to a 50 year old professor is not the same as what is clear to a 20 year old undergrad.

Comment: @Willie Maybe I see this now: Because we can always find an open set $U$ such that $f(U) = z$ for some fixed $z$, $f^{-1}(f(U)) \subset f^{-1}(z)$ which implies $f^{-1}(z)$ is open. Correct?

Comment: Aiye. That's the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use that $f$ is locally constant. =)

To show that a set is open, you need to show that every point in it is contained in an open ball. Analytically this is a local condition, since you can take the ball to be arbitrarily small. (Algebraically, however, one may choose a [topology where open balls are no longer intuitively local](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski_topology).) So basically, you cannot get away from using some local property of $f$.