# Path connectedness problem

Tags: general-topology

How can we formally show that this holds true:

> A locally path connected space is connected **iff** if it is path connected? True or False?

I think it is true, however I seem to be confused on how this can be shown. I would appreciate some nice way to show how the above statement is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $S$ is connected and locally path connected. For $a,\ b$ in $S$, there is a finite overlaping chain of base sets $\{ U_1, U_2,\cdots, U_n \}$ with $a \in U_1,\ b \in U_n$ and consecutive sets intersecting (since $S$ is connected).

Find some $x_j \in U_j \cap U_{j+1}$ for $j = 1\cdots n-1$. Since the $U_j$'s are path connected, construct a path from $  
a$ to $x_1$ to $x_2$ to $\cdots$ to $x_{n-1}$ to $b$.

Comment: He's using the cover-chain characterisation of connectedness I proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/44938/4280) FYI.

Comment: Didn't think about this way at all, its very nice method indeed, thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Recall that any topological space can be partitioned into its path components and the space is path connected when it consists of exactly one path component.

Let $X$ be a locally path connected. Its path components are easily seen to be open. We can therefore argue

> If $X$ is not path connected let $U$ be be the open path component
>   containing some points in $X$ with a nonempty complement. But the
>   complement $V$ of $U$ is the union of open path components and must be
>   open. But then $X$ has a nontrivial decomposition
>
> $\quad X = U \cup V$
>
> into two open sets and therefore $X$ is not connected.

Comment: Thank you, its very clear now.