# the cardinality of $p^{-1}$ is locally constant

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, covering-spaces

There is a staement in Hatcher's book:If $p:\tilde{X} \to X$ is a covering space,then the cardinality of the set $p^{-1}(x)$ is locally constant over $X$.

Does it mean that for any $x\in X$ there exits a neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ such that $|p^{-1}(U)|$ is a constant? How to check it?

Comment: It means that the function $n:X\to \text{cardinals}$, $n(x)=\lvert \{y\in \tilde X\,:\, p(y)=x\}\lvert$ is locally constant, i.e. that for all $c\in X$ there is an open set $U\ni x$ such that $n(x)=c$ for all $x\in U$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement implies that each $x \in X$ has an open neighborhood $U$ such that $|p^{-1}(y)|$ is constant for all $y \in U$.

To see why, let $U$ be an open neighborhood of $x \in X$ such that $p^{−1}(U) = \bigsqcup_{i\in I} V_i$ is a union of disjoint open sets in $\widetilde X$,
each of which is mapped homeomorphically onto $U$ by $p$. Then each point $y \in U$ has exactly one preimage in each $V_i$. It follows that $|p^{-1}(y)| = |I|$.

Comment: If $X$ is a connected space,how to show that the cardinality of $p^{-1}(x)$ is constant for all $x\in X$?

Comment: Any local property is global on a connected space. See this question for a proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/44850/4583