# Locally homeomorphism on connected space

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I am wondering since locally constant maps $f$ on connected space are contant, what about locally homeomorphic maps on connected space?

I am trying to mimic the proof by Thomas Andrew here [Locally Constant Functions on Connected Spaces are Constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44850/locally-constant-functions-on-connected-spaces-are-constant) showing locally constant + connected = constant, by replacing $\{x\ |\ f(x)=f(x_0)\}$ with the maximal neighbourhood of $x_0$ such that $f$ is homeomorphic on it. Is that the right way to do it? Or maybe they are just not homeomorphic.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Are you asking if a local homeomorphism on a connected space is always a homeomorphism?

Comment: Yes I am asking if a local hoemomorphism on a connected space is homeomorphic

Comment: There is a positive result along these lines, but you need to strengthen the assumption: Require the target to be simply connected and $f$ to be a covering map. You can find details in any algebraic topology textbook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot prove that every local homeomorphism with a connected domain is a homeomorphism, since that is not true. For instance, if $f\colon\Bbb R\longrightarrow S^1(=\{z\in\Bbb C\mid|z|=1\})$ is the map defined by $f(x)=e^{ix}$, then $f$ is a local homeomorphism, but it is not a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

No it’s not true:

Take the parametrization of $\mathbb{S}^1$

$\gamma: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{S}^1$

sending $\alpha$ to $(cos(\alpha), sin(\alpha))$

In this case $\mathbb{R}$ is a connected space and $\gamma $ is a local homeomorphism (it’s a covering map and $\mathbb{R}$ is the universal cover of $\mathbb{S}^1$) but $\mathbb{R}$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1$