# Locally constant functions in connected set

Tags: connectedness

If $\Omega\in \mathbb{R^n}$ is a connect open set,function $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is continious and locally constant.
Prove:$f$ is constant function.

I try to construct a "path" to connect $x$ and $y$, but in fact $E$ is not path connected，so this can't work.

Comment: what is $E$? Also, I'm not sure if you've seen this before, but if $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is connected and open, then you can conclude that $\Omega$ is path-connected.

Comment: It follows from the definition of connectedness. That it is in $\mathbb R^n$ is not important. (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44850/locally-constant-functions-on-connected-spaces-are-constant?rq=1))